# Error converting data type nvarchar to float in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.SCOPE
    ,convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 112) AS EFFECTIVE_START_TIME
    ,'99991231' AS EFFECTIVE_END_TIME
    ,LV.UOM_CODE
    ,'Gross Price' AS COLUMN_NAME_0
    ,CONVERT(float,LV2.VALUE_0) * CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_1) AS VALUE_0  
    ,'Quantity' AS COLUMN_NAME_1
    ,LV.VALUE_1
FROM 
    PM_SCOPE S 
JOIN 
    PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON S.SCOPE_ID = LV.SCOPE_ID
JOIN 
    PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
JOIN 
    PM_SCOPE S2 ON S2.COMP_PRODUCT = S.COMP_PRODUCT  
JOIN 
    PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV2 ON LV2.SCOPE_ID = S2.SCOPE_ID
JOIN 
    PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD2 ON LD2.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV2.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
WHERE 
    LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details' 
    AND LD2.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Gross Price List'
    AND S.GEOGRAPHY = S2.GEOGRAPHY
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, LV2.UPDATED_AT, 112)  > CONVERT(VARCHAR, LV.UPDATED_AT, 112)
```

When I run it, I get this error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

However when I comment out the below line, it works

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, LV2.UPDATED_AT, 112)  > CONVERT(VARCHAR, LV.UPDATED_AT, 112)
```

I looked at the data and unable to figure out the reason I see this error.

I also looked at the existing posts for this error and they don't seem to help me.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data? You can find the offending values with `try_convert`. What is the actual datatype of `updated_at`, I'm confused by the error, since it looks like your converting a `date` to a `varchar`, which shouldn't be a problem. Unless the error is in `CONVERT(float,LV2.VALUE_0)`, but it should still error when you comment the last line...

Comment: I suspect the issue might be the greater than comparison - why are you converting to varchar before doing this?

Comment: @HoneyBadger the datatype of UPDATED_AT column is [datetime].

Comment: Does it still error if you don't convert `updated_at` to `varchar`?

Comment: You can use try_convert so that it will return null during error values.. Correct way is to find the data and provide appropriate fix

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, absolutely right, I meant you can use it to find values that can't be converted, then it's more easily fixed.

Comment: it is probably that LV2.VALUE_0 or LV.VALUE_1 is actually not numeric you can test by using isnumeric(lv2.value_0) = 0 to see if something is not numeric.  Otherwise it is also possible that one of your ID fields is actually not numeric and you are comparing it with a numeric data type.  I would have suspected your Converstion of UPDATED_AT as well and it could still be an issue but it does work although there are better ways of testing if 1 date is larger than another

Comment: An example of data in UODATED_AT column - 2015-03-08 02:17:49.000

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you, you will need to provide table structure and data that reproduces the issue.   If we can't see actual data that actually results in this error, we can't determine the cause of the error.  By the way, why are you converting dates to varchar for purposes of doing a `>` comparison????

Comment: when i use try_convert here, it works for me but i still dont understand the reason and the difference TRY_CONVERT(float,LV2.VALUE_0) * CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_1) AS VALUE_0

Comment: TRY_CONVERT will return NULL instead of an error. This allows the rest of your code to run.

Comment: @scsimon  return NULL where?  you mean the value of VALUE_0 will come as NULL?

Comment: Why are you actually casting to `float`? `Float` is an approximate datatype, `decimal` is a better fit for prices.

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY_CONVERT(float,LV2.VALUE_0) * TRY_CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_1) AS VALUE_0  --This will return NULL since the TRY_CONVERT results in a NULL for one of the columns, and NULL * anything is NULL
CONVERT(float,LV2.VALUE_0) * CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_1) AS VALUE_0          --This will error out since you can't convert a nonnumeral to a FLOAT

SELECT ISNUMERIC(LV2.VALUE_0), ISNUMERIC(LV.VALUE_1)                       --This will tell you which column is causing you problems
```

Here is some test data examples

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(float,'12.2y') * TRY_CONVERT(float,'12.25')       --This will return NULL since NULL * anything is NULL
SELECT CONVERT(float,'12.2y') * CONVERT(float,'12.25')               --This will error out since you can't convert 12.2y to a FLOAT
SELECT ISNUMERIC('12.2y'), ISNUMERIC('12.2')
```

Comment: this is weird, for all my data I just see 1 when i do ISNUMERIC.

Comment: Do you have some real large numbers in this column?

Comment: no in LV.VALUE_1 column, the value is always 1. And in LV2.VALUE_0 I am storing some prices like 1236 ,238.58, 0, 95768.99 etc....

Comment: Are there commas in your values? This will cause the error but still return 1 for ISNUMERIC. i.e. `select convert(float,'14,569,845.66')`

Comment: No commas, only periods.

Comment: @Tanu Does this return any rows: `SELECT LV2.VALUE_0 FROM PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV2 WHERE TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,LV2.VALUE_0) IS NULL`